# can i write express middleware this?

Tags: node.js, express

```
/configure
const express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    routes = require("./routes"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    morgan = require("morgan"),

 const App = (app) => {
    app.use(morgan("dev"));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false,
    }));
    app.use(cookieParser("secret"));
    app.use(routes);
    app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
    return app;
};

module.exports = App;
```

export and import

```
/main app
const app= express(),
**configure = require('/configure);**

**configure(app);**
```

i read Web Development with MongoDB and NodeJS.
any read book never seen this way.
i thing write this good way read code

1. can i write this?
2. why i write this?
3. recommand best way write express middleware

Answer (score 0):

- Yes you can write it this way.
- Personaly I do it this way when I have many routes or middlwares because it helps me to keep my app.js file clean,
- I create a separte file for routes, and another one for config which may includes logging and and other config initialization